# How to replace unicode characters in string with something else python?

Tags: python, unicode

I have a string that I got from reading a HTML webpage with bullets that have a symbol like "•" because of the bulleted list. Note that the text is an HTML source from a webpage using Python 2.7's `urllib2.read(webaddress)`.

I know the unicode character for the bullet character as `U+2022`, but how do I actually replace that unicode character with something else?

I tried doing
`str.replace("•", "something")`

but it does not appear to work... how do I do this?

Comment: What is the type of the string, and which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7, string is formed from urllib2.read()

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not going to download a webpage using `urllib2` now. What is the `type`? `str` or `unicode`?

Comment: Have you tried u.encode('ascii', 'replace') and then replacing '?' ?

Comment: How do I tell what the "type" is? I just assume that whatever text I get from the webpage download would just be a normal string.

Comment: @Damascusi: `type(str)`. There is, unfortunately,no "normal string" type in Python 2.x; there are two string types.

Comment: I tried print type(varcontainingstring) and the output I got was <type 'str'>

Comment: if your python code contains utf-8 characters, you should use the 'magic comment' `# coding=utf8` in the first or the second line of your code.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

1. Decode the string to Unicode. Assuming it's UTF-8-encoded:

   ```
   str.decode("utf-8")
   ```
2. Call the `replace` method and be sure to pass it a Unicode string as its first argument:

   ```
   str.decode("utf-8").replace(u"\u2022", "*")
   ```
3. Encode back to UTF-8, if needed:

   ```
   str.decode("utf-8").replace(u"\u2022", "*").encode("utf-8")
   ```

(Fortunately, Python 3 puts a stop to this mess. Step 3 should really only be performed just prior to I/O. Also, mind you that calling a string `str` shadows the built-in type `str`.)

Comment: I get this error: `TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly`

Comment: could you please elaborate in what way "Python 3 puts a stop to this mess"? How would I do this in Python 3 then?

Comment: I get: `.decode("utf-8")` -> `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Did you mean: 'encode'?`

Answer (score 16):

Encode string as unicode.

```
>>> special = u"\u2022"
>>> abc = u'ABC•def'
>>> abc.replace(special,'X')
u'ABCXdef'
```

Comment: what is "special"? I get a nameError: name 'special' is not defined.

Comment: @Rolando  Notice 'u' has been prefixed in string, that makes it unicode string.

Answer (score 9):

Try this one.

you will get the output in a normal string

```
str.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
```

and after that, you can perform any replacement.

```
str.replace('•','something')
```

Comment: This proves useful when the `\u` sequence is actually present as is in the source string.

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
regex = re.compile("u'2022'",re.UNICODE)
newstring = re.sub(regex, something, yourstring, <optional flags>)
```

Comment: It is not an asterisk, it is a bullet (circle shape)

Comment: When trying: re.sub(u'2022', varcontainingstring, ''), it makes the string empty with nothing in it.

Comment: @Damascusi fixed - try it now

Comment: @NullUserException Why is it a bad idea to use a regex to replace fixed strings?

Comment: @AntonTeodor Regex is less efficient than a simple string search and replace. It will work though

Answer (score -1):

```
str1 = "This is Python\u500cPool"
```

Encode the string to ASCII and replace all the utf-8 characters with '?'.

```
str1 = str1.encode("ascii", "replace")
```

Decode the byte stream to string.

```
str1 = str1.decode(encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore")
```

Replace the question mark with the desired character.

```
str1 = str1.replace("?"," ")
```

Answer (score -2):

Funny the answer is hidden in among the answers.

```
str.replace("•", "something")
```

would work if you use the right semantics.

```
str.replace(u"\u2022","something")
```

works wonders ;) , thnx to RParadox for the hint.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to remove all \u character. Code below for you

```
def replace_unicode_character(self, content: str):
    content = content.encode('utf-8')
    if "\\x80" in str(content):
        count_unicode = 0
        i = 0
        while i < len(content):
            if "\\x" in str(content[i:i + 1]):
                if count_unicode % 3 == 0:
                    content = content[:i] + b'\x80\x80\x80' + content[i + 3:]
                i += 2
                count_unicode += 1
            i += 1

        content = content.replace(b'\x80\x80\x80', b'')
    return content.decode('utf-8')
```