# Replacing a unicode character in a string in Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, unicode, replace

I have a string where some of the characters appear as unicode, e.g.:
"bla bla bla \uf604 bla bla bla"

I tried doing `string = string.replace("\uf604", "X")`, but nothing happens. I tried to decode the string to utf-8, but apparently that doesn't work in Python 3.

How can I replace the character?

Comment: "tried to decode the string to utf-8"...?

Comment: like in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093727/how-to-replace-unicode-characters-in-string-with-something-else-python

Comment: Ah, from utf-8. There's a lot of confusion about encoding unicode/decoding bytes stemming from Py2. Could you add to your question a bit more details about what and how you've tried? If you get tracebacks, add them too.

Comment: Cannot replicate with Python 3 – that is, the replacement works.

Comment: line.decode("utf-8").replace(u"\u201c", "X").encode("utf-8")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: how do you display the input string? Is there a literal backslash in it or is it just a Unicode escape sequence that is used in the text *representation* of the string (only printable characters represent themselves, non-printable characters are escaped). Note: `'A' == '\u0041' != r'\u0041'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 3, this works (although the `print` may not, depending on your terminal):

```
>>> s="bla bla bla \uf604 bla bla bla"
>>> print(s)
bla bla bla  bla bla bla
>>> s="bla bla bla \uf604 bla bla bla"
>>> s.replace('\uf604','X')
'bla bla bla X bla bla bla'
```

But perhaps you have a *literal* slash and not an escape code.  Note the `print` difference:

```
>>> s="bla bla bla \\uf604 bla bla bla"
>>> print(s)
bla bla bla \uf604 bla bla bla
>>> s.replace('\uf604','X')
'bla bla bla \\uf604 bla bla bla'
```

Use a escape slash to fix:

```
>>> s.replace('\\uf604','X')
'bla bla bla X bla bla bla'
```

Comment: That's only one, but not very generic if a string contain many unicode char