# Replace sequences in Python

Tags: python, text, replace

I want to  make a replacement script.

It should replace str1 to str2.
My file has xml-based structure.
For example, I have:

```
...word1'#13#10'word2'#13#10'word3... = ...word1'#13#10'word3...
```

I want to remove some part of string.
I use this in a script:

```
Lines[i] = Lines[i].replace(key, DataBase[key])
```

I've already checked that "key" and "DataBase[key]" are correctly defined. If I print them into console with "print()" - it looks just like it has to.
But then script is executing it don't change sequences like this - with '#13#10'. Pairs of keys without any specific simbols works fine.
What can I do? And why it doesn't works well?
Full script:

```
import configparser
#import time

config = configparser.ConfigParser()  # init configparser
config.optionxform = str
config.read("SocratToCortesExpress.cfg")  # config file

print("Config file - readed")

filePath = config.get("PATH", "old_file")  # config file - with names of files, pairs of words

DataStrings = config.items("DATA")  # read pairs
DataBase = dict()  # initialization of dictionary
print("Dictionary - initialized")

for Dstr in DataStrings:  # old and new words for a replacement
    SocratName = Dstr[0]
    CortesName = Dstr[1]    
    DataBase[SocratName] = CortesName


print("Dictionary - fulfilled")

with open(filePath, "r", encoding='utf-8-sig') as ResultFile:  # input file    Lines = ResultFile.readlines()

print("Old file - uploaded")

f1 = open('logkeys.txt', 'w')
for key in DataBase.keys():
    try:
        f1.write('\n'+key+'\n'+DataBase[key]+'\n')
    except Exception as e: #errors
            f2 = open('log.txt', 'w')
            f2.write('An exceptional thing happed - %s' %e)
            f2.close()
f1.close()


for i in range(len(Lines)):  # brutforce - all over input file
    #Lines[i] = Lines[i].replace('\ufeff', '') #some weird symbol
    for key in DataBase.keys():     
        try:
            Lines[i] = Lines[i].replace(key, DataBase[key]) #replacing  
        except Exception as e: #errors
            f2 = open('log.txt', 'w')           
            f2.write('An exceptional thing happed - %s' %e)
            f2.close()


print("Sequences - replaced")

outFileName = config.get("PATH", "new_file")  # define output file

print("Exit file - initialized")

with open(outFileName, "a", encoding='utf-8-sig') as outFile:  # save
    for line in Lines:      
        outFile.write(line)

print("OK")
```

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the parts of the script you haven't shown; can't be sure for obvious reasons.

Comment: Please add your code, so we can help.

Comment: Looking at what you have shown so far, there does not seem to be an error. The problem will probably be in the parts that you didn't show. Perhaps if you posted more of the code, we could help better.

Comment: `It should replace str1 to str2` -> What's wrong with `s = s.replace(str1, str2)`?

Comment: I'm not sure I would call that xml based data

Comment: Just added full code. "XML-based" - I meant that it is .xprt file with structure familiar to .xml.

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve]? Input file as well as expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
>>> s = "word1'#13#10'word2'#13#10'word3"
>>> s.replace("'word2'#13#10'", '')
"word1'#13#10word3"
```

Comment: So, I tryed. But is script, not shell. And nope, it doesn't work. Maybe because of my word2 in cyrillic characers

Comment: It has nothing to do if this is a script or run interactively. For UTF-8 replacement, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093727/how-to-replace-unicode-characters-in-string-with-something-else-python

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maybe I'm on the right way now. I'm already using UTF-8 encoding: open(filePath, "r", encoding='utf-8-sig') . It helps me to read file correctly, including BOM. But still, I can't replace my string which includes '#13#10'. I don't know, maybe there is the way to find and replace sequences in bytes, not strings? Firstly encode my strings, make a replace and after that encode it to UTF-8 again. But I'm not sure if replacement in bytes exists.