# How to scrape NON-ASCII characters alone

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape data. The text I want to scrape is "€ 48,50", which contains an ascii character. However, I would like to replace the euro sign with nothing so that the final output is "48,50". I have been getting errors because the console cannot print it. I am using python 2.7 on Windows for this. I will appreciate a solution.

I was basically getting errors and do not know how to go about this. Or is there a way I can just extract non-ascii characters alone?

```
w= item.find_all("div",{"class":"product-price"}).find("strong",
{"class":"product-price__money"}).text.replace("\\u20ac"," ")
print w
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode the string and pass the replace function a unicode string.

```
text = "€ 48,50"
w = text.decode("utf-8").replace(u"\u20ac"," ")
print w
```

See [How to replace unicode characters in string with something else python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093727/how-to-replace-unicode-characters-in-string-with-something-else-python) for more details.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I ended up using at the time. I needed to decode the character