# How to remove \xa0 in unicode from a list

Tags: python, encode

I hope to remove \xao in the word of python list. Each word is a unicode type.

I have used replace method to get rid of \xa0, but it does not work.

```
list = [u'apple\xa0', u'banana']

list = [el.replace('\xa0',' ') for el in list]

print list
```

The expected res is:

```
list = [u'apple', u'banana']
```

The actual res is:

```
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace unicode characters in string with something else python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093727/how-to-replace-unicode-characters-in-string-with-something-else-python)

Comment: BTW, if you are wanting to _remove_ the character instead of _replacing it with a space_, you will want to make the second argument of the replace `''`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `u` at the beginning of your string:

```
[el.replace(u'\xa0',' ') for el in list]
```

I would also avoid using `list` since it is a built-in function in Python.